# error when adding click event to datagrid in powershell script

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to add a `Add_CellMouseClick` event to my existing powershell script. however after adding the code I keep getting an error in powershell (see below). the code I am adding is based off of [Powershell datagridview cell click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284508/powershell-datagridview-cell-click-event) and a couple other pages that I cant seem to find again to reference. I think I am probably missing something simple but can't find what that might be.

I have tried a few variations of the code but keep getting the same error. unfortunately I cant find much in the way of examples of what I am trying to do. also cant seem to find any powershell documentation on this method just c#.

existing xmal code for the datagrid (this works same as the code for filling the datagrid)

```
<DataGrid Name="HistoryGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" Margin="19,536,-365,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="353">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding E1}"  Header="Employee #"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding E2}"  Header="Employee Name"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding E3}"  Header="Employee Username"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

2 options I tried

`$HistoryGrid.Add_CellMouseClick({HistoryClick})`

or

`$HistoryGrid.Add_CellMouseClick({if ($_.button -eq  'Left'){HistoryClick}})`

What I want to happen is when someone clicks on one of the entries in the datagrid it runs the HistoryClick function. unfortunately I get the error below instead. which is why i think i'm missing something.

> Method invocation failed because [System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid]
>   does not contain a method named 'Add_CellMouseClick'. At
>   Utility.ps1:141 char:1
>   + $HistoryGrid.Add_CellMouseClick({if ($_.button -eq  'Left'){HistoryCl ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound